# NGX-TRANSLATE V13 import causes error on ANGULAR12 + IVY

Tags: angular, ivy, ngx-translate

@ngx-translate/core

Import of core package cause problem.

```
   'TranslateModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.(-996002)
    public_api.d.ts(10, 37): This likely means that the library (@ngx-translate/core) which declares TranslateModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
```

impl:

```
   imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot(),<--- error
```

I can NOT disable IVY because it has no result.

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
"enableIvy": false, <- Does nothing
```

HELP

angular@12
ngx-translate@13

Comment: Cannot reproduce. In a fresh Angular 12 project, ngcc processes the library (note the `Compiling @ngx-translate/core : es2015 as esm2015` output in the console), and the application builds and runs as expected. Please add a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: It worked, idk why ngcc is not attached to package.json instantly. Thank you so much friend.